# How to have concurrent async calls in a nested map function

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await

I have an object, that has a nested array of objects, which has another nested array of objects. I have an asynchronous function that checks if they are valid. I want it to run concurrently, but I want to wait on all of the promises to return. Right now I have:

```
function validate(userId): Promise<User> {
  let user = await this.userRepo.findById(input).catch(err => this.handleNotExistent(err))
  let friends = user.friends || []
  await Promise.all(friends.map(async friend => {
    let validFriend = await this.friendRepo.findById(friend.id).catch(err => this.handleNotExistent(err))
    if (validFriend.name != friend.name || validFriend.age != friend.age) {
      this.handleInvalidRequest()
    }
    else {
      let friendOfFriends = friend.friendOfFriends || []
      return await Promise.all(friendOfFriends.map(async friendOfFriend => {
        let validFOF = await this.FOFRepo.findById(friendOfFriend.id).catch(err => this.handleNotExistent(err))
        if (validFOF.name != friendOfFriend.name) {
          this.handleInvalidRequest()
        }
        else {
         return validFOF
        }   
     }
   }
}
```

How can I rewrite this, so that it runs in order (you need to find validFriend first before you can look up their friendOfFriend, but all of the mapped items run concurrently?

Comment: Right now, both of the mapped Promises are already running in parallel. 1) The top-level `Promise.all` on `friends`, and 2) the nested `Promise.all` on `friendOfFriends`. And your other criteria is also met: "find `validFriend` first before you can look up their `friendOfFriend`".

One thing to keep in mind is that the function signature shows a return of `Promise<User>`, but currently nothing is being returned.

Comment: sorry, I excluded the return statement at the end. So all of the friends are being validated concurrently and not sequentially?

Comment: @VikramKhemlani Yes it is running concurrently. It looks like there is nothing wrong with this code. You could make the `!=` into `!==`.

Comment: It depends on exactly what you want as a final output. As it stands, you will end up with an array containing arrays of friends_of_friends but there's no attempt to filter out invalid friends at either level.

Comment: It would make sense to return an array of *validated* friends each with a property containing an array of *validated* friends (ie validated friends of each friend).
If that's what you want then you need to do two things for each of the maps (1) return `friend` if valid or something falsy (eg `null`) if not valid (don't throw), then (2) filter the mapped array to purge nulls leaving only valid friends. You would also need to attach the validated friends of each friend as a property of the original friend.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 that's good advice. At first I didn't want to be able to accept invalid friends because it is a mobile app, and that would have meant something wrong in the code that sends a request to this route, but maybe filtering invalid stuff is probably a better route.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Nested structure to unpack
2. How to wait on multiple promises

It would have been ideal if you could have made the code standalone and runnable on the TypeScript playground (obviously, you'd have to make this a simplified version of the real thing), because then it'd be easier to show you unwinding it.

But in spirit, the first approach I'd take would be like:

```
async function validate(userId): Promise<User> {
  ...
  let friends = await findFriendsAndTheirFriends(userId)
  return Promise.all(friends.map(validateFriend))
}
```

The first function, `findFriendsAndTheirFriends()` (you'd have to write that, of course), takes a given user ID and returns a list of friends and their friends. The second function takes each friend `userId` and returns a promise that will validate that friend.

But I don't think the way you've got exactly two levels of friends is good. Aside from being hard to read, it's very inflexible, and near impossible to debug.

You'd be better off turning it into some kind of graph problem, where you search for all nodes (user IDs) connected to your node (your user) by a distance < 3.

The beauty of that approach is that it would still work with the code above, just that the `findFriendsAndTheirFriends()` function would do the graph search behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! But wouldn't the find friends and their friends be the same mapping function? (that finds friends through a loop and their friends). and if I return an array of objects, that have a nested array (friends and friends of friends), I would be going throw the same information twice, first to find, then to validate? Also, do you have any links to graphing functions, I can't seem to find anything and I'm using postgres which is a relational database, so theres' no graphs.

Comment: @VikramKhemlani, as written in the question, there are three differences between first level and second level validation:
(i) prop of user against which unvalidated friends are stored `.friends` vs `.friendOfFriends`.
(ii) repo 'friendRepo' vs 'FOFRepo'.
(iii) friend properties validated, `.name && .age` vs `.name`.
If you wanted to find friends and friends_of_friends by the same function, these differences would need to be cated for or eliminated in the overall design.